# Not able to call method of WCF webservice on https URL

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, ssl

Today I've problem while we are calling "https" WCF service method from local website. we have following error message while we call service from localhost.

"An error occurred while making the HTTP request to "https://....". This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server."

We also host the same service with "http://" on server and it's works as expected. And also we check the same service hosted in local IIS with SSL certificate and it's works also fine in local so now we stuck at this point. Any idea about what we check for proper configuration on server or anything else?

Here i share our configuration file for "https://" service.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>    
    <add name="VISION" connectionString="ConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceName.Service1Behavior"
        name="ServiceName.Integration_Service">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"   
          bindingNamespace="" contract="ServiceName.Contracts.IEnquiry">
          <identity>           
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"
          bindingNamespace="" contract="ServiceName.Contracts.ITenant">
          <identity>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"
          bindingNamespace="" contract="ServiceName.Contracts.ICreditInformation">
          <identity>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"
          bindingNamespace="" contract="ServiceName.Contracts.IIncomeDetails">
          <identity>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"
          bindingNamespace="" contract="ServiceName.Contracts.ITenantAddress">
          <identity>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"
          bindingNamespace="" contract="ServiceName.Contracts.IAdditionalDetailOfApplicant">
          <identity>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"
          bindingNamespace="" contract="ServiceName.Contracts.ITenantLinkStatus">
          <identity>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"
          bindingNamespace="" contract="ServiceName.Contracts.IResendTenantLink">
          <identity>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"
          bindingNamespace="" contract="ServiceName.Contracts.IGenerateReports">
          <identity>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"
          bindingNamespace="" contract="ServiceName.Contracts.IGetApplicantStatus">
          <identity>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"
          bindingNamespace="" contract="ServiceName.Contracts.IUploadDocument">
          <identity>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"
          bindingNamespace="" contract="ServiceName.Contracts.ICompanyIncomeDetails">
          <identity>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
 <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" /> 
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
     
      <wsHttpBinding>  
        <binding name="TransportSecurity">  
          <security mode="Transport">  
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>  
          </security>  
        </binding>  
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceName.Service1Behavior">
         <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="50" maxConcurrentSessions="50" />
        </behavior>
       
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
   
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>

    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Please revert me back if you need any more on this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Are you using the same binding security and transport type on the client binding?

Comment: Yes, It's same on client @Popo